# How to reimplement methods deprecated now that Android 10 is out? For working with MediaStore and storage?

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring, deprecated, mediastore

I'm working on refactoring my older app. Decided to migrate to Android Q/10 finally. My app works with sound files so there are 2 methods which are deprecated now. How to implement the same functionality the new way?

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(outPath); //outPath is the path where I save my .wav file.
...
```

```
String externalRootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        if (!externalRootDir.endsWith("/")) {
            externalRootDir += "/";
        }
        subDir = "media/audio/music/myfolder/";
...
//getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated. Here I'm making a filename for my recording
```

Also I'm using this constant

```
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, outPath); //DATA deprecated
```

How to reimplement these parts? It is my first time with android Q (and I'm not much experienced in all Android yet anyway). Thanks in advance!

Comment: "How to implement the same functionality the new way?" -- you are going to need to fundamentally change what you are doing, but we do not know what your app does (beyond "works with sound files"). It will be difficult for anyone to give you advice.

Comment: I implemented Storage Access Framework where the users are asked to provide access to both internal and external media. The other option is to look at scoped storage but given my app raeds and writes to both types of sdcard, scoped storage did not meet my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In Android 10 there is a new MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH that helps you to define a ‎location to save the file, the problem the allowed directories for audio files are [Alarms, Music, ‎Notifications, Podcasts, Ringtones], you can't just specify any directory you want.‎

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        collection =  MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY); // added in @api<=29 to get the primary external storage

        // To specify a location instead of the default music directory in external
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, (Environment.DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS).getAbsolutePath());
    }else{
        // Your Old code
    }
Uri itemUri = resolver.insert(collection, values);
```

If you don't add MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH the file will be saved at the default ‎directory which is "Music"‎.

I still don't know how to save it to my package folder in Android 10: context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS)